# php upload_max_filesize changed but still gives that error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i changed the values in php.ini but until now i couldn't upload the plugin and still gives the same errot (The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.)

changed the values in php.ini but it still gives the same error

Comment: Did you restarted web server ?

Comment: Also check the webserver config to match the max body size with the number in php config

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 :**
Add these values in `.htaccess` file to increase the file upload size

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

**Method 2 :** By Editing `wp-config.php` file

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '512M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '13M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '15M' );
```

You can try any of these methods to increase the file upload size